# First time using prepared statements but query is not activating

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have just started using prepared statements as it was brought to my attention by another user. However, after I started to implement it, it doesn't seem to properly add the new record to the database. When I click on Submit, it just shows the register success div that I have setup.

login.php (Where the form is located)

```
<form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="col-md-3 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname" class="col-md-3 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="age" class="col-md-3 control-label">Age</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' maxlength="3" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Age">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="region" class="col-md-3 control-label">Region</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="region" placeholder="Region">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address" class="col-md-3 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Postcode" class="col-md-3 control-label">Postcode</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="language" class="col-md-3 control-label">Language</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="language" placeholder="Language">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <!-- Button -->                                        
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i>Submit</button>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#signupform").bind('submit',function() {
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
                var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
                var age = $('#age').val();
                var region = $('#region').val();
                var address = $('#address').val();
                var postcode = $('#postcode').val();
                var language = $('#language').val();
                $.post('scripts/register.php',{username:username, email:email, password:password, firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname, age:age, region:region, address:address, postcode:postcode, language:language}, function(data){
                    $('#signupsuccess').show();
                }).fail(function(){{
                    $('#signupalert').show();
                }});
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

register.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `Username`, `Password`, `Email`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Age`, `Region`, `Address`, `Postcode`, `Language`) VALUES ('NULL', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')");
$stmt->bind_param(NULL, $username, $password, $email, $firstName, $lastName, $age, $region, $address, $postcode, $language);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$region = $_POST['region'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$language = $_POST['language'];
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your server's error logs? [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I am running this inside of a WAMP server so that the PHP is being executed, I'm not sure why but the AJAX is not access register.php at all. I've tried running echos inside of it but it completely skips it out. However, I do know that it is getting into the $.post('scripts/register.php',{username:username, email:email, password:password, firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname, age:age, region:region, address:address, postcode:postcode, language:language}, function(data){
                    $('#signupsuccess').show(); loop as it is displaying #signupsuccess properly

Comment: I see the problem - you're getting values from elements you think have id's (like `#username`) but none of your inputs has `id="username"`

Comment: Am I seing that right that you first bind unknown variables to your statement and THEN read the variables in from $_POST?

Comment: Omg... How did I not notice that?! Now I feel like an utter noob.

Comment: @MichaelRitter I followed most of a tutorial on W3School that did it like that, is that not how it's supposed to be?

Comment: I don't know. Haven't progged php in a while. Just fix the id issue of Jay and if it works, ignore my initial comment :)

Comment: It'll work like that @Chromatic, but for organization sake many will transmute the variables before writing the query or the bind. As Spock says, *"It is only logical."*

Comment: Yeah, tbh it was Jay who pointed out that I should use prepared statements. So now I'm overthinking everything and thinking it has a next level problem that I've not solved... but turns out to be IDs xD

Comment: You can alwas just print all variables on the server (or echo them back). Also: always nice to validate the input on server-side (check if all variables are actually present via $_POST)

Comment: I was thinking that when I saw it on W3School, but I thought if it worked for them then that must be the traditional way. I'll move the variables around as well. Do you have any other security measures I should be doing as well @JayBlanchard ?

Comment: You're in pretty good shape right now and have come a long way since this morning @Chromatic ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hmm, after giving them all the correct ID, it still doesn't add it to the database, it just displays the success

Comment: Watch the request/response in the browser's developer tools. It is typically under the Network tab and will reveal problems that you might not be seeing otherwise. I have to bail out for the evening @Chromatic, but tag me with questions and I'll get back to you as quickly as I can.

Comment: Okay @JayBlanchard Thank you for everything today :) If anyone else wants to tackle this error: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Invalid type or no types specified That's the error I got, I can see what line it is. It's this one: $stmt->bind_param(NULL, $username, $password, $email, $firstName, $lastName, $age, $region, $address, $postcode, $language);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting values from elements you think have id's (like `#username`) but none of your inputs has `id="username"`. You can either add the id's to your input elements or you can change your selectors, e.g. `$('[name="username"]')`

Comment: This did solve part of the issue, the rest was because in the prepare, in my VALUES I had ('?', '?') which is incorrect, I had to remove quotations and just have the question marks.